# What's the meaning of "lay out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this statement:

> Had to send this in a hurry as partner walked in... and now I can' edit the post.
>
> As with the re'homing of the cats.. they are my kids.. I can't. And
>   even if it were to get to that stage, it's another thing that's going
>   to happen, showing what a failure I have become..
>
> I am sorry to be **laying this out** here,..

This is a post by a user on a suicide forum seeking advice. I am guessing *laying out* here means something like 'writing this post here'? he is sorry for posting his story here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Laying** it all **out**

means to put it out for display so that anyone can see (read), show it all

> It's all **laid out** in plain view.
>   Let's **lay out** the jewellery on the table so we can see it better.
>   We're **laying out** the silverware to polish and count it.